# Getting more details on a specific memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

My memory leak looks like this:
[image: leak]

Having not that much experience with the `Eclipse Memory Analyzer` i wonder if it can answer those two questions:

- What's the source code position where most of those instances were allocated?
- What's the reason they were not garbage collected?

  1. Did they stop but are still referenced somewhere?
  2. Are they still executing or sleeping?

**EDIT:** Looks like *sbridges* was right and my threads just never die. However i'm not really sure of the reason since the stacktrace doesn't seem to contain any of my code. The way i use ExecutorService must be wrong somehow.

[image: threads]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere your code is creating threads, and those threads never die.  Threads can't be garbage collected, since a thread is a gc root.  The easiest way to debug this will be to start the app, wait until you have a large number of threads, then connect to the app with [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), and look at the stack traces of the threads.  To see stack traces, click on the [threads tab](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole/ThreadsTab.jpg) and click on a thread under live threads.

Comment: You were right. I edited my post. If you got any further thoughts let me know.

Comment: Are you calling shutdown on your executors when you are done with them?

Comment: That's likely to be the problem, thanks. Out of curiosity... is there any static code analysis tool that would issue a warning in such a case (Class instantiated but essential method never called)?

Comment: Probably not in this case, it is common to create Executors that live for the lifetime of the application, and are never shutdown.

Comment: I verified it. You were right about shutdown(). Thanks alot :)